# Deploy multiple wars with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a project that contains two sub projects (sub-project-1 and sub-project-2).  Each of the sub projects is a .war project that, when by itself, deploys successfully to my localhost.  However, when I try and deploy both using the parent project my gradle build stops working.  Here's what I am seeing from the commandline:

```
C:\dev\parent>gradle jettyRun
:sub-project-1:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:sub-project-1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:sub-project-1:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Building 37% > :sub-project-1:jettyRun > Running at http://localhost:8080/sub
```

Any ideas how I might get this working and deploying both sub projects?

Comment: I have not done something similar to this in gradle but i would suggest to check if there are any conflicting dependencies between these war files and also check their web-contexts for any conflict.

Answer (score 1):

[jetty plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) has `jettyRun` task that creates a custom Jetty configuration to run WAR produced by containing project, starts this Jetty and waits until it finishes. It is similar to `application` plugin. It means it works in context of one (sub-)project. When you quit this first jetty you will see the second one from `sub-project-2` started.

You may want to take a look at [Gretty](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/) plugin. It supports newer versions of Jetty and Tomcat and also the docs suggest that there is a support for multiple web-apps.